# LWC - Run Event on Child when Datable Row Selected on Parent

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, parent-to-child

I am trying to run an Event on my Child Component when the Datable row is selected on my Parent Component.
I am receiving the error below

Here is the Event code from my **Child Component**

```
handleCancel(event){
    const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll( 'lightning-input-field' );
    if ( inputFields ) {
        inputFields.forEach( field => {
        field.reset();
        this.showSaveButton = false;
        } );   
    }
}
```

Here is the Event code from my **Parent Component**

```
handleRowSelection(event){
        var selectedRows=event.detail.selectedRows;
        this.werRecordId = selectedRows[0].Id;
        this.template.querySelector('c-work-experience-record-page').handleCancel();
        this.werSelectedRow=true;
    }
```

**Error**

```
[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs196/auraFW/javascript/nv49ahbZfs85wzJXOZaywA/aura_prod.js:1000:112
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs196/auraFW/javascript/nv49ahbZfs85wzJXOZaywA/aura_prod.js:1000:305
dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs196/auraFW/javascript/nv49ahbZfs85wzJXOZaywA/aura_prod.js:13:46387
Na.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/cs196/auraFW/javascript/nv49ahbZfs85wzJXOZaywA/aura_prod.js:13:13839
Na.fireSelectedRowsChange()@https://falcon-pe--dxtest.sandbox.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:1:95086
Na.zn()@https://falcon-pe--dxtest.sandbox.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:1:49259
Na.handleSelectionCellClick()@https://falcon-pe--dxtest.sandbox.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:1:93785
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Please edit your question with more details.

Comment: I have added the error

Comment: Is this line supposed to have two assignments?  `selectedRows=el.selectedRows=el.selectedRows.slice(1);`

Comment: I want to limit the selection to 1 row

Comment: Why are you querying the DOM for the rows?  Couldn't you just do `selectedRows = selectedRows[0]`?

Comment: Yes - the query is unnecessary.   Given the max-row-selection=1  on the table it is not really coming into play.  The selected row in the table is working fine.  I am just receiving an error when trying to call the handleCancel event from the Parent on the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue....
I forgot to add an @api decorator on the Event in my Child Component to expose it to the Parent.

```
@api
handleCancel(event){
    const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll( 'lightning-input-field' );
    if ( inputFields ) {
        inputFields.forEach( field => {
        field.reset();
        this.showSaveButton = false;
        } );   
    }
}
```